# sagemaker calling curl with inference endpoint with csv

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a random cut forest model endpoint on AWS sagemaker. I am trying to test the inference endpoint with POST man. I am successfully able to authenticate into the endpoint with access and secret key.
Can someone confirm if the way I am sending the csv payload is correct ? It seems something is not working since whatever the third column value, I get the same score from the endpoint.
'1530000000000,E39E4F5CFFA2CA4A84099D2415583C1C,**433190.06640625**'

Pasting the curl for the POSTman generated code:

curl --request POST \
  --url https://runtime.sagemaker.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/endpoints/randomcutforest-2018-06-05-01-08-02-956/invocations \
  --header 'authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=/20180713/us-east-1/sagemaker/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=d51371b2549e132c21a3402824b57258a74e6fa9f078d91a44bf54b0d110ea57' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: text/csv' \
  --header 'host: runtime.sagemaker.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' \
  --header 'postman-token: cb7cdfa5-025b-e4f4-c033-a4fb685133c4' \
  --header 'x-amz-date: 20180713T190238Z' \
  --data '1530000000000,E39E4F5CFFA2CA4A84099D2415583C1C,433190.06640625'

```
{
    "scores": [
        {
            "score": 7.6438561895// This value never changes
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your second column is not numeric is suspicious. RandomCutForest is only supposed to work with numbers.

I'd recommend you use the AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285

Would you be able to share the feature_dim you used to train the the forest?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved this issue. You are right on!   I used the magnitude of the time series alone and this worked with the response changing based on the input